# Is it possible to build a solid state water pump?

Tags: electromagnetism, water

Water consists primarily of permanent dipoles and some dissolved ions. The force on a dipole is given by
$$\vec{F} = \left(\vec{p}\cdot \nabla\right) \vec{E}.$$
Is it possible to produce a net force on water in a pipe by taking advantage of this fact? I'm imagining a setup where two rings carrying opposite charges outside of the pipe polarize the water, making it possible to exert a net force on the water because $\langle\vec{p}\rangle \neq 0$. The gradient in the electric field would be supplied by Faraday's law applied to a sequence of conductive rings that all have an unbalanced [sawtooth wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave) being fed into them. The gradient comes from the sawtooths having increasing amplitude as you move down the pipe.

Granted, there would be drawbacks from possible induced electrolysis if the system is run too hard, but I'm curious if this is even possible.

Comment: Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetohydrodynamic_drive they run a current through sea water and then move it with the magnetic field. A bit different, but perhaps something to start with.

Comment: My gut feeling is that the electric dipole moment of a water molecule is too small and the electric fields that would be required would be too high to make the idea practical. Probably a big problem just generating such large electric fields in water since unless it's ultra-pure it's not an excellent insulator. I've heard about using the Lorentz "j x B" force to push water, and that's probably a much more practical approach for moving water without using any moving mechanical parts.

Comment: Apparently yes MAGNETO-HYDRODYNAMIC (MHD) PUMP
FABRICATED WITH CERAMIC TAPES http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1129&context=meam_papers

Comment: I have been wondering the same. Here is a setup I have come up with https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/708774/physics-of-an-electrostatic-water-pump-is-it-even-possible but I am still trying to figure out if it would work.

Answer (score 2):

Even for a very large electric field of 30 V/mil, and considering only the force acting in one direction rather than any cancelling force at the other end of the active area, I am finding a pressure of $½E^2·(\epsilon_r - 1)·ε_0$ = 0.072 (psi), so it seems impractical.

Answer (score 1):

Piezolectric pumps, such as http://www.servoflo.com/micropumps/mp6 , might be a reasonable replacement for what you describe.

Comment: Not really different from a normal solenoid aqurium air pump